# Mamba F405 gps loiter mode

Tags: betaflight, flight-controller

I ordered a new mamba f405 a few months ago and I am  curious whether it is possible to have loiter mode on Mamba f405 flight controller like one in pixhawk ?

Answer (score 1):

The Betaflight firmware has very few GPS assistance modes. AFAIK, the only one is [GPS Rescue Mode](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/wiki/GPS-rescue-mode) which allows the quad to return to where it took off in an emergency.

For more GPS modes, I'd recommend looking into the [iNav firmware](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/wiki), which has a lot more options for you and [supports the Mamba F405 flight controller](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/releases). The iNav GPS mode you'd be looking for is the [`NAV POSHOLD` mode](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/wiki/Navigation-modes#nav-poshold---Position-hold), which allows a multirotor to maintain a constant 3D location in space.